# hybris error installing secureportal addon

Tags: installation, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to install the "secureportaladdon". While installing it using the command:

ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="secureportaladdon" -DaddonStorefront.yb2bacceleratorstorefront="yb2bacceleratorstorefront"

I am getting the error

BUILD FAILED C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\ext-addon\addonsupport\resources\addonsupport\ant\acc-ant-addons.xml:592: The following error o ccurred while executing this line: C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\ext-addon\addonsupport\resources\addonsupport\ant\acc-ant-addons.xml:508: The following error o ccurred while executing this line: C:\work\trail\hybris\bin\ext-addon\addonsupport\resources\addonsupport\ant\acc-ant-addons.xml:354: Storefront template p arameters are missing. Set at least one storefront parameter (addonStorefront...) in command line : ant addoninstall -Da ddonnames="AddOnName1,AddOnName2" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="B2CStorefront1,B2CStorefront2" -DaddonStoref ront.yb2bacceleratorstorefront="B2BStorefront1,B2BStorefront2"

Am i missing any template property to be set in the accelerator? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, did you include *< extension name="secureportaladdon" />* in the localextensions.xml file?
If so, instead of the ant command to install the addon you can alternatively add the *"secureportaladdon"* to *< requires-extension >* in the *extensioninfo.xml* file of your storefront.
Now, is *"yb2bacceleratorstorefront"* the storefront you want to add it to?
You can go to the administration console and check in platform/extensions, see if that extension you want is included and if its the one you want to use. If you have used the accelerator to generate your own storefront you would need to install it in *yourgeneratedshopstorefront*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already done this. Still the click of Login gives me a Page not found error.

Comment: Can you give a little more details?
What login button? If you get prompted the login page when trying to access the frontend, it is quite likely to get a 404 error from the hybris console, probably due to some server startup errors. Or you mean loggin in from the actual end user page?

Comment: Yes, Juan.. I am trying to logging in from the actual end user page.

Comment: Well, without more details is going to be hard to solve... Are both extensions visible in the hac? Do you get some errors when the server starts? Is the start up time normal? Is there any difference in the url before installing the addon and after? etc.

Comment: I think as well, that you have some issues with your extension configuration. Have a look here: 
https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/8aeddd34866910149de2d448ff18df98.html
*AND* 
https://help.hybris.com/6.4.0/hcd/8adf7365866910149ceb975f778d809d.html